# How to take away fraction part from decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, decimal

How to take away fraction part while formatting decimal type in .NET? I need common syntax for both variants. Is there any gentle solution?

```
            decimal a = 1.22M;
            decimal b = 1.00M;

            String.Format("${0}", a); // result is $1.22
            String.Format("${0}", b); // result is $1.00, should be $1, HOW?
```

Comment: String.Format("${0}", b.Replace(".00",string.Empty));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that 'common syntax' means that you need one solution to give both outputs, `String.Format("${0:#.##}", x)` does the trick. When `x` is `1.00M`, the result will be `"$1"`. when `x` is `1.22M`, the result is `"$1.22"`.

Comment: But if that thing is 0, the output is empty. I got "$" instead of "$0".

Comment: @user337085, try my approach which is not elegant as formatting but will work in any case... String.Format("${0}", anyvalue.Replace(".00",string.Empty));

Comment: @user337085: Use `0.##` instead of `#.##`. That will fix your problem when the value is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Try these - both will output the appropriate currency symbol for the current system:

```
a.ToString("C2");  // Outputs 2DP
b.ToString("C0"); // Outputs no DP
```

If you need to supply a specific currency symbol, use the same as above, but substitute N for C.

Comment: @eugeneK - in what way - he wanted a common way to output a decimal as a string with specific numbers of decimal places.  Which is what this does...

Comment: Nopes, he wanted to show decimal value with fractions when there are any... "Common syntax for both solutions"

Comment: @Paddy, then it's unfair because we've got different time zones and i'm already on the second cup...

Answer (score 2):

The `Decimal` type is designed to keep track of how many significant digits it has. That is why `1.00M.ToString()` returns the string `1.00`.

To print a `Decimal` without the factional part you can use the format specifier `N` with precision `0`:

```
1.22M.ToString("N0") => "1"
1.00M.ToString("N0") => "1"
1.77M.ToString("N0") => "2"
```

This will round the `Decimal` in the conversion process.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET I would use

```
 CINT(INT(a))
```

I imagine a C# variant exists.

I found a probable solution at this link:

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

To further explain:

```
decimal a = 1.55M;
Console.WriteLine("$" & CInt(Int(a)).ToString()); // result is $2

decimal b = 1.22M;
Console.WriteLine("$" & CInt(Int(b)).ToString()); // result is $1
```

I would steer away from utilizing the currency format as the decimals are inherent to that class.

Comment: if the value is decimal in first place INT(value) will remove fractions.

Comment: CINT(INT(a)) ensures proper rounding

Comment: Then if the value would be 1.22, it will round to 1 as INT() does when he wants to get 1.22 and just to remove .00 in case where is no fractions

Comment: First of all, INT() drops the decimal.  There is no rounding.

Comment: Second of all, Int() comes out as a Short.  The CINT would then convert it to an Integer.  CInt in itself actually rounds the number.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I would do to drop the decimals off the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("${0:0}",b)
```

In C# you can use `{0}` to tell a parameter, and `{0:format}` to tell a parameter with format.

**EDIT**

Oh I thought what OP want to do is removing the digits of b. But now I realized that he wants to remove useless zeroes.

```
string.Format("${0:#.##}",b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues here I think. If the question is to completely ignore decimal places, then just casting to an integer would produce the required output, but would obviously loose precision, which is not a good thing.

There are also rounding considerations when formatting as a string like example below.

```
decimal a = 1.55M;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("C0")); // result is $2

decimal b = 1.22M;
Console.WriteLine( b.ToString( "C0" ) ); // result is $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is just for dispaly and **not for changing data type to INT when number has no value after decimal.**

using System;

```
namespace stackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal a = 1.2245M;
            decimal b = 1.00M;



            Console.WriteLine("Your percentage to date is: {0:#.#####}", a);
            Console.WriteLine("Your percentage to date is: {0:#.#####}", b);//#.#### gives number upto 4 decimal
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n, x;
            int a, dec = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter double");
            n = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            a = Convert.ToInt32(n);
            x = n - a;
            if (x < 0)
                a--;
            int k = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < n.ToString().Length; i++)
            {
                if (n.ToString()[i] == '.')
                    k = i;
                if (i > k)
                    dec = dec * 10 + (n.ToString()[i]-48);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Non-fraction " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("Fraction " + dec);


            Console.ReadKey();

        }


    }
}
```